# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq

Tags: g++, libpqxx

I want connect to postgresql by libpqxx (C++)

When running g++ with -lpq I got this error:

```
 [michael@michael cpp]$ g++ Store.cpp -lpqxx -std=c++11  -lpq
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
 status
```

When I remove -lpq it's run well and work, I want to know why with -lpq it's not work and how fix it.

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: This is strange.  This page: http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/ says that  the -lpq is needed, but your compile worked without it.